# Как запустить selenium в боевом режиме?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как запустить selenium web driver через python таким образом, чтобы браузер запускался в обычном режиме а не тестовом.

По факту мне просто нужно автоматизировать несколько процессов по работе с сайтом, но лучше это делать в обычном режиме, но селениум постоянно открывает в тестовом режиме. Может быть  есть альтернатива как можно автоматизировать процессы на сайте (заполнение форм и тд) через python?

Comment: Что такое "в тестовом режиме"?

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про профили, сессии, и сохранение куки в селениум, думаю, вопрос заключается в этом

Comment: @Эникейщик каждый раз будто в "инкогнито", без сохранения сессии

Comment: Т.е. нужно сразу после запуска быть авторизированным на каком-то сайте?

Comment: @Эникейщик судя по всему да, уже дали ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял - Вам подойдет запуск определенного профиля. Сначала создайте этот профиль и настройте как Вам угодно(Добавьте расширения, пройдите аутентификацию на нужных Вам ресурсах). Далее:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Ваш_username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Ваш_профиль")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Путь к профилю смотрим тут:
chrome://version/

Драйвер загрузит предварительно настроенный Вами профиль для конкретных задач.
Возможно, Вам еще пригодится:

```
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Так драйвер не будет закрывать браузер по окончании работы и Вам проще будет отладить код при поиске нужного элемента для парсинга.

Comment: Спасибо большое) попробую)